# Simple JavaScript empty string check, what does (an empty string) mean and why is it failing?

Tags: javascript, string

Here's my code:

```
$("#ddlCiudad").change(function () {
    var idCity = $("#ddlCiudad").val();
    $.getJSON("/ProductCheckout/GetPriceForLocation", { cityId: idCity, productId: idProduct, type: "land" },
        function (cityData) {

            console.log("Recieved json data.");                    

            landCost = cityData.LandCost;
            $("#billingshippingcost").text(landCost);
            console.log("Assigned value of LandCost");

            airCost = cityData.AirCost;
            console.log("Assigned value of AirCost");

            console.log(landCost); //Logs: 25,00
            console.log(airCost); //Logs: "(an empty string)"

            if (landCost == "") {
                $(".land").removeClass("land").addClass("land-disabled");
            }
            else {
                $(".land-disabled").removeClass("land-disabled").addClass("land");
            }

            if (airCost = "") {
                $(".air").removeClass("air").addClass("air-disabled");
            }
            else {
                $(".air-disabled").removeClass("air-disabled").addClass("air");
            }

        }
    );
});
```

That `if` statement is **not** being fired, any suggestions on why it's not firing?

Maybe `an empty string` isn't the same as "" in Javascript.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `if (airCost == "")`?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ Yeah I fixed that already. :) The error still stands however. That condition is not passing.

Comment: Are you sure? Add something like `console.log('airCost is empty')` in the `if` block just to check if it gets there (and it's just the classes that aren't being added and removed correctly)

Comment: Btw, that edit doesn't apply. It completely changes my questions intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if (!airCost) {
    $(".air").removeClass("air").addClass("air-disabled");
}
else {
    $(".air-disabled").removeClass("air-disabled").addClass("air");
}
```